# Sum of Multiple Cells Between Date Range

Tags: excel, vba, date, range, sumifs

I have a sheet with some stored pricing info that is dated.  Column A has a list of stored dates and Columns K, L, and M need to be added together and subtracted by the sum of column E, if they're within the given date range.  Q1 is the location in which you choose the start date in format "7/15/15", and Q2 is the location in which you choose the end date of the desired range.  Here's some images to help with what I'm describing:

[image]

Disregard the second image "Average Profit" cell, that should be titled "Total Profit"

[image]

Comment: Did you see my last comment yesterday?  The location in which you choose the end date of the desired range is not Q2, but instead it is Q4 and that is most likely why it's returning 0. It looks like row 2 and 3 are hidden.

Comment: Wow, great catch!  Although, even after fixing the macro I still get 0.. was sure that your find was the fix..

Comment: Hmm. Does the formula that I provided you a couple nights ago work after making that change?

Comment: No it does not.  Still returns 0.. I cannot figure this thing out.  Seems easy on paper.

Answer (score 0):

Here, my approach for your problem with VBA.

```
Public Sub summarizeValue()

    Dim total As Long
    Dim row As Integer

    'Set start row
    row = 5

    'Work with sheet
    With Sheets("sheetname")

        'Loop until date cell is blank
        Do While .Range("A" & row) <> ""

            'If all date cell are valid
            If IsDate(.Range("A" & row)) And IsDate(.Range("Q1")) And IsDate(.Range("Q4")) Then

                'If date is valid between two range.
                If .Range("Q1") <= .Range("A" & row) And .Range("A" & row) <= .Range("Q4") Then

                    total = total + .Range("K" & row) + .Range("L" & row) + .Range("M" & row) - .Range("E" & row)

                End If

            End If

            row = row + 1

        Loop

        .Range("Q7") = total

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: I went through the code and everything seems to be fine, to me it should work.  But after running the script, "0" was returned..  VBA seems to be the best solution though.  Maybe a bit of tinkering will resolve the issue.

Comment: You should modify your sheet name at `With Sheets("sheetname")`. If it is, It will work well. I already tested it. I think you should debug the code, if not sure.

Comment: I've already corrected the code prior to running it.  The correct sheet name is in the VBA and still returns "0".

Comment: I think that your date value are not valid, so it return 0 every time. Please debug it while running code.

Comment: My logic is check dates and if ok, sum K, L and M and subtract E from that total. Finally, I set total value to Q7. If you use my code, there is only away to get error, that is date values are not valid. If one of date values are not valid, summarizing process is not work. One thing is that looping is start from row 5. I think that it get 0 when subtract E from total.

Comment: Other file had an issue, uploaded download link to current file in the main post.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83392/discussion-between-nicolas-and-user3059686).